# Вопросы по SEO

Tags: seo

Приветствую.

1. Стоит ли добавлять сайт в поисковики,каталоги и тп, если ещё сайт постоянно обновляется и иногда становится недоступным? Если можно - то как это повлияет на саму индексацию?
2. Многие поисковики ( особенно наш Яшка и многие русские ) индексируют по огромному количеству времени. Тот же Яндекс может почти месяц индексировать сайт. Что за это время можно сделать для "укрепления позиций" и стоит ли делать это вообще?
3. Слышал что вредно кидать сайт уже заполненный материалами и будет правильней кинуть сайт с парой страниц и потом его активно обновлять и добавлять материалы. Это так?
4. Ещё слышал что не стоит забивать сайт материалами очень быстро (т.е. по 100 в день) а лучше периодично небольшой массой в промежутке 1-2 дней. Типа как спам поисковики воспринимают =). Это так?
5. Значит закроем глаза и представим что есть сайт...Домен приобретён не давно...В индексацию не где ещё не падал...Делается движок и дизайн...Скиньте какую нибудь хорошую статью или сами объясните поэтапно как его можно поднять в поиске и вообще "раскрутить".
6. Часто вижу такую фишку что сайт стоит уже 2-3 года без дела и нечего на нём не происходит...И он в топе или вообще первый. А другой сайт который также по тому же запросу каждый день обновляется находится ниже. От чего такая "несправедливость"?

ps. Да искал я в интернете - только каждый своё говорит : либо противоречащие другим людям либо откровенный бред либо еще - "Кидайте ссылку на сайт куда только можно!"

pps. Заранее Спасибо :DDD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Стоит добавлять в ограниченное количество редактируемых каталогов, типа DMOZ, Яндекс.Каталог и т.п. Лучше, конечно, подождать когда сайт будет работать стабильно, иначе есть вероятность, что редакторы посетят ресурс именно тогда, когда он будет недоступен.
2. -
3. Для поисковой машины не имеет значения начальное количество документов, но имеет значение частота обновления сайта (как часто появляются новые документы), поэтому есть смысл добавлять понемногу.
4. Вполне можно не только по 100, но и по 1000 ежедневно. Типичный пример - сам форум ХэшКод. Здесь ежедневно по 50 новых тем добавляется. И все отлично индексируется и ранжируется.
5. В конечном счете все сводится 1) к контекстной рекламе, 2) ценности информации (товаров, услуг), предлагаемой на сайте. Различные творческие методы (вирусная реклама, конкурсы и акции) по своим затратам (продумывание, разработка, осуществление) не дешевле прямой рекламы. Если информация ценна, целевой посетитель придет.
6. Один сайт может иметь преимущество над другим, если 1) на него ссылается большее количество более авторитетных тематических ресурсов, 2) текст заголовка и содержание страницы в больше степени соответствуют запросу, 3) текст ссылок на ресурс более подходит по запросу.

Comment: 2? :D Насчёт 5 - ну чтобы донести товар до пользователя или инфу надо же раскрутить..Может я не понимаю чего то но замкнутый круг :DDDD Возможно поэтому из 3 сайтов 2 только 2 года активно функционируют а потом или стоят или ликвидируются...потому что просто забивают пока их пользователь найдёт :DDDD

Comment: Вообще да. Но многое зависит от типа ресурса: магазин, энциклопедия и форум по разному развиваются.

Comment: Как говорят представители Яндекса - забудьте о всех этих сеошных штучках, делайте качественный, уникальный контент и боты к вам потянутся.